# soon need, or need soon?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I was reading a story when there was the following sentence fragment, "..., it was nothing like what we would need soon."

I respect this author and I believe he is careful with his words and their placement, however, I wondered whether "need soon." is more grammatically correct then "soon need?"

Also, if it works either way, grammatically speaking, what if any, changes in meaning are there?

NOTE: I notice there are several questions about soon, with a few considerations of placement, so if this is actually a duplicate, I will have no issue with VtC as duplicate.

Comment: _What we would need soon_ is from _We would need X soon_, where _X_ comes out as _what_. In other words, there's a noun between _need_ and _soon_, but only its gap remains to separate those two words. But it does indeed separate them, and in fact _need soon_ is not a constituent and doesn't follow the rules you were thinking of.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Asoon).

Comment: I'd also choose  '[The demand for money was great, but] it was nothing like what we would need soon', but would choose 'If only we had realised how much money we would soon need'. The first contains a comparison/contrast, which is the only attempt at justifying this I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more about semantics than grammar.

> It was nothing like what we would **need soon**.

suggests that you won't need it, with the emphasis on that thing, with 'soon' suggesting 'ever' or 'never'.

> It was nothing like what we would **soon need**.

suggests that you do need some things, but this isn't one of them, and the emphasis is on things you need for a particular task.

Comment: I don’t read the “need soon” version as you do. For me the OP’s examples are essentially interchangeable. If I understand your interpretation, it’d be conveyed something like, “It was nothing we would need anytime soon.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum *We will need something soon. We will soon need something. Soon we will need something.* When you pull out the *something* for the *nothing like* version, it leaves behind a version that at surface value may look like "a thing" that it really is not. That's what John was saying.

Answer (score 1):

"Soon" can occur either before or after the main verb. Compare:

1. He will soon need help.
2. He will need help soon.

If you replace the object with the gap corresponding to the relative "what," you get:

1. ...what he will soon need.
2. ...what he will need soon.

These two are equivalent. I don't perceive any difference in emphasis.